# Junit4 test JsonSyntaxException failing

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Am testing a class that throw JsonSyntaxException the test keep failing even though am expecting the expected error is thrown .
My test:

```
@Rule
    public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none()  ;
    @Test
    public void customersJsonToJsonObjectMalformatedJson() {
        String malFormated = "resources/customerTestMalformated.txt";
        exception.expect(JsonSyntaxException.class);
        Invitation.customersJsonToJsonObject(malFormated);
    }
```

My try catch Block:

```
try {
    for (String line : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath))) {
        JsonObject jsonObjCustomer= (JsonObject) new JsonParser().parse(line);
        jsonObjCustomers.add(jsonObjCustomer);
    }

} catch (JsonSyntaxException e ){
    System.err.println(e.getClass());
}
```

The exception is thrown but the Test is not passing . can someone spot what am doing wrong please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ExpectedException` is only successful, if one of the invoked methods throws the defined Exception back to the caller instead of returning a value or void.

Your current implementation of `Invitation.customersJsonToJsonObject()` may throw a `JsonSyntaxException` inside your for-loop, but the Exception is catched and logged inside the method. The method returns void, so JUnit doesn't see any Exception.

Solution: Either remove the try-catch or change the test a look for the logged Exception.